# Using both append() and appendTo() at the same time

Tags: jquery

I am a noob and am confused by some example code in [the jQuery API documentation for event.preventDefault:](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<div id="log"></div>

<script>
$("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
$('<div/>')
    .append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
    .appendTo('#log');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why are both append() and appendTo() used here? Shouldn't one be enough? Why is the self-closed `$('<div/>')` used instead of simply `$('<div>')`?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `.append()` and `.appendTo()`?

Comment: The code is creating a div element, then appending some text to it, and then appending all of that to an element.

Comment: this part : `appendTo('#log')` should probably reads `appendTo($('#log'))`

Comment: @Johnny5 no, jQuery accepts a selector as argument too.

Comment: @dystroy: Could you explain that further? When is it ok to leave out the $ function in jQuery arguments?

Comment: @user2433865 Each jQuery function accepts its own set of arguments. If you look at [appendTo documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) you see it accepts a selector (`"#log"`), a jQuery element (`$("#log")`), an element (`document.getElementById('log')`) or some html.

Comment: Thanks for breaking everything down! You've been super helpful. I feel like getting the jargon down is the steepest part of the learning curve, so examples are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<div/>').append('default ' + event.type + ' prevented')
```

returns the div to which was appended the text.

And this div is appended itself to the `'#log'` element.

Chaining function calls is what makes useful to have the two functions.

From the documentation :

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major
>   difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the
>   content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding
>   the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With
>   .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and
>   it is inserted into the target container.

As per your second question, `$('<div>')` could have been used in place of `$('<div/>')`, yes, but the purpose (adding a whole element) is a little more evident with the latter.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I hadn't realized it was creating a whole new div element; I thought it was just appending text to the original div. 

So you can self-close a div tag as short-hand when creating a new div?

Comment: When you pass HTML to the $ function, it makes a fragment, which is forcibly made of complete elements, not half ones. So  `$('<div>')`, `$('<div/>')` and `$('<div></div>')` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

append() insert the argument to tue element, and appendTo() inserts the selected elemento in the element put as argument